# How can I determine the number of times a header is processed?

Tags: c, header, gnu-toolchain

For the moment, my C codebases compile relatively quickly. However, I would like to utilise an *informed* approach to reducing the number of times a given header is re-processed.

I guess that being able to see reference counts would help me to do so. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both CLang and GCC support the `-H` option. It will dump into the console each header file included. Then, you can easily read these lines and analyze them to detect compiler bottlenecks.

From `man gcc`:

> `-H` Print the name of each header file used, in addition to other normal activities.  Each name is indented to show how deep in the `#include` stack it is.
>
> Precompiled header files are also printed, even if they are found to be invalid; an invalid precompiled header file is printed with `...x` and a valid one with `...!`.